# Get length in xslt

Tags: javascript, xslt

I'm trying to use a template that appends white space to a string.

```
    <xsl:call-template name="append-pad">
      <xsl:with-param name="padChar" select="' '" />
      <xsl:with-param name="padVar" select="$value" />
      <xsl:with-param name="length" select="15" />
    </xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="append-pad">
    <!-- recursive template to left justify and append  -->
    <!-- the value with whatever padChar is passed in   -->
    <xsl:param name="padChar" />
    <xsl:param name="padVar" />
    <xsl:param name="length" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($padVar) &lt; $length">
        <xsl:call-template name="append-pad">
          <xsl:with-param name="padChar" select="$padChar" />
          <xsl:with-param name="padVar" select="concat($padVar,$padChar)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($padVar,1,$length)" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

But the length of the with space is dynamic. This is what I tried in javascript but I get an error saying 'NAME cannot begin with '' when trying to debug the xslt.

```
function firstName(name) {
    try {
        var n = name.toString;
        var target = name.length - 20;
        var whiteString = "";
        for ( i = 0; i < target; i++) {
            whiteString.concat(" ");
        }
        n = n + whiteString;
        return n;
    } catch(err) {
        return "                   ";
    }
}
```

How can I do this logic in xslt?

```
    <xsl:value-of  select="concat(substring('                    ', string-length() +1), $firstName)"/>
```

Comment: From your javascript, can we assume the max length of string + padding is 20 characters? If it is, then the xslt `concat(substring('                    ', string-length() +1), .)` should do what you want. (where ' ' is 20 spaces)

Comment: @dash not exactly sure what you doing there, if I'm replacing the ' ' with 20, where will i specify ' '(whitespace) is what is being added?

Comment: It's the formatting of comments! `substring('{this is actually 20 spaces}', string-length() + 1)` will produce a string of white spaces that is `20 - length` of your string. You then `concat` this in front of your original string to give you the left padding.

Comment: @dash so it would be like i posted above?

Comment: That looks right except you need `string-length($firstName) + 1` as you want the length of the variable - give it a try :-) I would have posted this as an answer except your initial requirements weren't very clear to my, I'm afraid.

Comment: Works great! Thanks. You should submit it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, from your JavaScript example, you always want to pad the string up to a maximum of 20 characters, then you can simply use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('                    ', string-length($firstName) +1), $firstName)" />
```

How does this work?

First take the expression: `substring('                    ', string-length($firstName) +1)`

This will take the string of 20 spaces, and return a string of spaces that is `20 - length` of `$firstName` as we are using substring to only extract a portion of the string.

We then use the `concat` function to join the two together. We put the substring of spaces first to pad left (although we could always put them second if you wanted to pad right).

Answer (score 1):

In select you have to use an expression.
To set constant values in your param do this

```
  <xsl:with-param name="padChar"> </xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="length">15</xsl:with-param>
```

Comment: i'm not using a constant in my case